# How to input and output parameters upon jupyter event widget (on button click)

Tags: python, jupyter

While building a prototype frontend for a python app in Jupiter, I'm using the ipywidgets to facilitate interaction with the backend (basically a recommendation engine).

The desired behaviour is when a button is clicked the "UI" is refreshed based on the users feedback (rating items on some scale).
So new items are displayed based on this feedback.

However, the button.on_click(function), does not allow:

1. the function to return output(the user input)
2. nor can I pass parameters (input from the previous rounds) to the
   function.

I can work around this by:

1. Setting up a global parameter for the output(not my favourite
   solution either)

But I cannot work around:

2. Passing input to the function

I've already used a global variable and used a function definition to pass input to the function which is called, however that input is not global.

ideally it should work like this:

```
def on_button_clicked(inputs):
   item_characteristics = pd.read('items.cvs') 
   dash, inputs = recommendation_dashboard(input,      item_characteristics)

   display(dash)
   return inputs


   def recommendation_dashboard(user_input, item_characteristics):
     items = function to pick items based on user_input from previous round and item characteristics.



     form = [set of ipywidgets to display information on items,
       set of buttons to rate said items]


      return HBox(form),inputs
```

ideally:

`new_items_button.on_click(input = on_button_clicked (input) )
HBox([new_items_button])`

So the function goes through these steps:

1. there is a function to deal with empty user input (generates random
   examples)
2. shows items
3. user gives feedback (ticks differents radiobuttons)  after which the
   user clicks new_item_button and:
4. the function should return this inputted feedback and pass it to the
   recommendation_dashboard such that when the button is clicked for
   new items, based on this input a new set of items is displayed
   (which can be subsequently rated).

when I try to return the inputs by using a global variable and pass inputs to the function by defining:

`new_items_button.on_click(on_button_clicked (input))`

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

I don't think there is any fancy error handling implemented here so that's difficult to parse.

and when I do 
`new_items_button.on_click(input = on_button_clicked (input) )`

> TypeError: on_click() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inputs'

(which is logical but frustrating)

its impossible to retrieve the input as the input form is created by using a function and therefore the input is not accessible globally..

So is it possible to pass variables to a function called by an on_click event? (as in these variables change between button presses so no static definition suffices).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you, but I think one way
to do what you want is to use a method of an object to handle
the click event and encapsulate any state you need in
the object as in the following screenshot which implements a counter that counts how many times the button has been clicked.

[image]

Also remember that `f(click())` will evaluate the `click`
function and pass the result of that to `f`.  I think
in your question you really wanted `f(click)` which passes
the function value of `click` to `f` without evaluating it.

Comment: Thanks, ill take a look to implement and post my results in a week for future reference!